# Bind the same data to different form elements in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Let say user can advanced search by many conditions such as colors for somethings on responsive website.

**colors** can select from **checkbox** in **page** when screen > 768px but that advanced search will disappear when screen size < 768px and appear icon on top right corne. When click that icon, appear advanced search from right side like android nav drawer and set the colors to `select` element (multiple select).

Following code is ok on checkbox:

```
<label ng-repeat="(color, enabled) in colors">
    <input type="checkbox" value="color" ng-model="colors[color]"> {{color}}
</label>
```

using this data:

```
$scope.colors = { 'Silver': true, 'Gray': false, 'White': true, 'Brown': false};
```

How to bind data for `select` element using above data?

Or something needs to change above data format?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has the [`ng-options` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) which allows you to iterate over an object and supply `<option>` to a `<select>`. Given the right format, you can use that same object for your `<select>`.